# Почему при проверке условия только третий аргумент (arg3) проверяется на диапазон значения

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function getColor(arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0, arg3 = 0) {
`if( 0 < arg1 && arg2 && arg3 < 255 )` {
    if(arg1 && arg2 && arg3) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }else if (arg1 && arg2) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')'
    }else if (arg1) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }else {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }
}else {
    return 'Неправильное выражение аргумента, от 0 до 255'
}
};

getColor(23, 100, 1340);
```

Comment: Проверяются все три условия т.к., первые два выражения `true`, а оператор `&&` проверяется и третье, оно `false`.. Выражение `arg3 < 255` не проверяет диапазон значений.  Выражение `(0 < arg1 && arg1 < 255)` выглядит "странно", после `&&` всегда будет true смысл проверять число которое меньше `0`, меньше ли оно `255` это само собой разумеется.

Comment: Напишите отдельную функцию, которая проверяет одно значение на вхождение в диапазон и вызывайте её для проверки каждой из переменной. И вроде в JS можно замапить функцию на список переменных, так будет короче, но я это умею только в питоне делать.

Comment: Давай разберем это выражение из твоего "ответа" ниже `(0 < arg1 && arg1 <= 255)` если значение `arg1` по условию должно быть меньше `0` может ли оно быть равно `255`? Нет конечно. Оператор `&&` подразумевает в выражениях слева и справа от него `true`. Если `arg1` больше `0` второе выражение проверяться не будет, если меньше, то оно по любому меньше `255` и не может быть равно `255`. Второе выражение бессмысленное..

Comment: @Rudi вы не проснулись еще, да ?

Comment: @teran да, что не так, поправьте пожалуйста..

Comment: @teran Всё понял, затупил..

Comment: @Rudi например, эта часть - "Если arg1 больше 0 второе выражение проверяться не будет"

Comment: @Rudi вы пишите `0 < arg` и комменитируте как "arg должно быть меньше 0", что полностью обратное. Потом, "если arg больше 0 то второе выражение проверяться не будет", по факту в случае `0 < arg && ...` то второе выражение (в случае истинности первого) проверяться, конечно же, будет, это же все таки логическое И а не ИЛИ.

Comment: @Rudi просто напишите Ваш вариант как оптимизировать код, так как совет от  @@teran идеально вписывается в решение вопроса.

Comment: @Alex_ZD Если есть ответ, который "идеально вписывается в решение вопроса", зачем что-то ещё писать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы на вашем месте написал функцию в виде

```
function getRGBColorString(r = 0, g = 0, b = 0){
    if( [r,g,b].some( c => c < 0 || c > 255) ){
        throw new RangeError("Неправильное выражение аргумента, от 0 до 255");
    }

    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`; 
}
```

Comment: Я ученик и пока не совсем понимаю что выполняют такие методы как .some, throw new)))

Answer (score 0):

всего то немного логики в условии)

```
function getColor(arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0, arg3 = 0) {
    if((0 < arg1 && arg1 <= 255) && (0 < arg2 && arg2 <= 255) && (0 < arg3 && arg3 <= 255)) {
    if(arg1 && arg2 && arg3) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }else if (arg1 && arg2) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')'
    }else if (arg1) {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }else {
        return 'rgb(' + arg1 + ', ' + arg2 + ', ' + arg3  + ')';
    }
}else {
    return 'Неправильное выражение аргумента, от 0 до 255'
}
};
```

Comment: Возможно ли как то логически сократить данное условие?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: определить `const check = v => v > 0 && v < 256;` и использовать

Comment: @teran вот не могу теперь сообразить в каком месте это использовать, имеется ввиду так:
  if((check(arg1)) && ((check(arg2)) && ((check(arg3))

Comment: Например так, да. Или можно проверить а-ля `if([a,b,c].some( v => v <= 0 || v > 255)) return false;`

Comment: в целом остается не ясным, зачем у вас потом 4 ветки ифов, в которых вы всегда возвращаете одно и то же.

Comment: Это идеально считаю в данном случае!
Спасибо за Вашу помощь)

Comment: @teran - там передаются аргументы в функцию `getColor(23, 100, 1340);`
сначала идет проверка на диапазон, а после проверяется на наличие переданных аргументов в функцию, ведь можем передать вот так `getColor(23, 100,);`

Comment: @Alex_ZD у вас недостающие элементы по умолчанию нули. и вы их отсеиваете

Comment: Да, если передан  аргумент `getColor(23, 100);` выводит `getColor(23, 100, 0);`